# Positioning of elements inside a wrapper

Tags: css-position

i have a wrapper ("overview-nav") and three spans inside.
The span "overview-nav-current" is on the bottom of the first wrapper, and i am not able to drag it higher, so that it appears in the middle
float: top, margin-bottom, positive or negative doesn't work.

it would work if i would set it to `positon: relative` but then i have the problem, that the popover, above can not overlap the element if its positioned relative
[HTML-Popovers best-way / Positioning / Z-Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621289/html-popovers-best-way-positioning-z-index)

```
  <div id="overview-nav" style="z-index: 0">
    <% p = ($system_type_app ? select_times_path : invoicing_path) %>
    <span class="overview-nav-btn">
    <%= link_to far_svg('chevron-left'), p(date: p_overview[:back_date], view: p_overview[:view]) %>
      </span>
    <span id="overview-nav-current">
    <%= link_to "Today", p(date: 'today', view: p_overview[:view]) %>
      </span>
    <span class="overview-nav-btn">
    <%= link_to far_svg('chevron-right'), p(date: p_overview[:forward_date], view: p_overview[:view]) %>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "far_svg" is a helper and that generated a svg, which affected the span, with the text "Today".

I positioned a little div with a little text beneath the word "today" and then I was able to push the text a little bit higher.

That is really not the cleanest way, but, it works for now.